# When I split my C++ file into .h file and .cpp file, and then #include "xxx.h", the function defined in .cpp file is not valid

Tags: c++, compilation, linker

env:

> OS: Windows 10
>
> compiler: cygwin g++

To demonstrate the problem I meet, I create three files, `main.cpp`, `class.h` and `class.cpp`, all of which are located in the same dir.

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include "class.h"

int main(){
    Class c;
    c.fun();
    return 0;
}
```

**class.h**

```cpp
#ifndef class_h
#define class_h

class Class{
public:
    int i;
    void fun();
};

#endif
```

**class.cpp**

```cpp
#include <class.h>

void Class::fun(){
    i++;
    i++;
}
```

and the way I compiled my `main.cpp` is:

```
g++ main.cpp
```

however, it generated error like this:

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\temp>g++ main.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/9.3.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: /cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/cco3V0Lq.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): undefined reference to `Class::fun()'
/cygdrive/c/Users/xxx/AppData/Local/Temp/cco3V0Lq.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x15): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `Class::fun()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Could anyone help me.... thanks in advance ;-)

Comment: You compile `main.cpp`, but not `class.cpp`

Comment: `g++ main.cpp class.cpp`

Comment: Note that not initializing `i` before writing to it is Undefined Behavior. Not that that is necessarily your problem here. Just something to look out for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix), in particular [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix/12574400#12574400)